# Updating a view displayed by QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` widget which is filled with the help of `QStandardItemModel`.
In every two seconds the function containing these two classes is called using `QTimer` and next 50 entries are given.

The function runs properly after every two seconds but the values arent refreshed in the window displayed.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Code :

```
void Box::create_frame()
{
        k=0;
        tablegroup = new QGroupBox(tr("Table"));
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

        table = new QTableView(this);
        table->setUpdatesEnabled(false);

        cout << "recent check" <<endl;
        QStandardItemModel *mode = new QStandardItemModel(1,2,this);
        mode->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("ID")));
        mode->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("DATA")));

        map<int,QString>::iterator it;

        for(it=dataa.begin();it!=dataa.end();it++)
        {
                for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
                {
                        QStandardItem *item;
                        item = new QStandardItem();
                        item->setEditable(true);
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                                item->setData(((*it).first), Qt::DisplayRole);
                                mode->setItem(k,i,item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                item->setData(((*it).second), Qt::DisplayRole);
                                mode->setItem(k,i,item);
                        }
                }
        k++;
        }
        //setUpdatesEnabled(false);
        table->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
        cout << "create frame check" << endl;
        table->setModel(mode);
        layout->addWidget(table);
        tablegroup->setLayout(layout);
}

QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(refresh()));
        timer->start(2000);
}

void dataThread::run()
{
        boost::posix_time::seconds delay(2);

        int g=0;
        int h=50;

        while(1)
        {
                while(g<h)
                {
                        dataa.insert(pair<int,QString>(g+1,"HELLO"));
                        g++;
                }
                boost::this_thread::sleep(delay);
                h=h+50;
        }

}
```

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs i have edited the question and paste my code for the function that is creating table.

Comment: first fifty values are getting printed but next 50 are not.
when i add __cout << "(*it).first << endl;__ inside if then next fifty values are also displayed but not refreshed on the table

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs what were you checking that i have code or not?
now i do have,so HOW ABOUT HELPING ME ABOUT.

Comment: @user1479705 That is your setup code. Where is your update code? BTW there is no need to ask the same question twice.

Comment: @sgibb question edited with the asked code.
and it wasnt answered at the first time so i thought YES theres a need to ask ONCE MORE

Comment: @user1479705 Your first question wasn't answered after 3 hours. Please be more patient.

Comment: ok lets ignore every thing.and please please help me out i am in a fix how to solve this out. @sgibb

Comment: `dataThread::run()` only inserts data into your map `dataa` but not into your model `mode`. It seems you forgot to update your model (to fill new values into). Does @Blood's answer works for you? (I can't imagine but you marked it as *correct solution*.)

Comment: i did it by defining a new function an refreshing it using qtimer.and it qorked.thanks :D :D

Answer (score 0):

First, it's late here so maybe I'm overlooking something but from your run loop, it doesn't look like you are actually adding any data to your table's model rather you're just adding entries to your `dataa` vector/list.

Maybe you should add this to your run loop

```
while( g < h )
{
    dataa.insert(pair<int,QString>(g+1,"HELLO"));

    QStandardItem *item;
    item = new QStandardItem();
    item->setEditable(true);
    item->setData( g+1, Qt::DisplayRole );

    // You need the model here
    table->model()->setItem( h + g, 0, item );

    item = new QStandardItem();
    item->setData( "Hello", Qt::DisplayRole );

    // You need the model again here
    table->model->setItem( h + g, 1, item );

    ++g;
}
```

Again its late but I think you get the idea. You're currently not changing the model that your table is set to, rather just changing your `dataa` vector/list.